# how to prevent ios animation interrupted by socket message

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, socket.io

i am working on an ios app. the app shows an animation after receiving some data from a server via socket.io.

My problem is that the animation is interrupted or slowed by processing other data from the server via socket.io.

i am trying to suspend executing other data processing code once the animation starts and until the animation finishes.

in other programming language, such as java, i could use

```
synchronized
```

to accomplish this.

how can i do that in ios?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to shift your socket.io/data processing off to a background thread leaving the main thread free to run the animations.

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: “backgroundQueue”)
backgroundQueue.async { // do your work here }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your animations in a UI main queue.

DispatchQueue.main.async {   // do your animations here }

Thumbs up if it worked :)

Comment: The animations will already be executing on the main queue. I don’t think this will make any difference.